# Vuejs: Use stored data withing nuxt pages

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm using Nuxt as my front server and in pages folder there's an index page which I want to use vue-material autocomplete package in it. For that purpose, I have a plugin that imports my package as following:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
Vue.config.productionTip = false

import VueMaterial from 'vue-material'
import 'vue-material/dist/vue-material.min.css'
import 'vue-material/dist/theme/default.css'

Vue.use(VueMaterial)
```

Then in my page I have the following script which get the data from back and fetches it into the store's state:

```
export default {
  async fetch (context) {
    let { data } = await context.$axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/')
    context.store.commit('my_data', data)
  },
```

Now below this I have to use something like this which is suggested by [vue-material doc](https://vuematerial.io/components/autocomplete):

```
 data: () => this.$store.dispatch('my-data'), <- Doesn't work
  methods: {
    getMyData (searchTerm) {
      this.mydata = new Promise(resolve => {
        window.setTimeout(() => {
          if (!searchTerm) {
            resolve(this.my_data)
          } else {
            const term = searchTerm.toLowerCase()

            resolve(this.my_data.filter(({ name }) => name.toLowerCase().includes(term)))
          }
        }, 500)
      })
    }
  }
```

As you can see I want to load the the date that is previously saved in store. And none of the commands like `this.$store.dispatch` works. It always raise this error tat `this` is not defined.

I'm not sure if what I'm trying to do is the best way for this problem whatsoever but the point is that when I use a custom dictionary instead of data the autocomplete works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use asyncData to load the data from the store (https://nuxtjs.org/guide/async-data)

```
async asyncData(context) { 
  let result = await context.store.dispatch('my-data')
  return {
    data: result
  }
}
```